# Using Task Record Type via REST API

Tags: rest-api, record-type

We have a number of picklists that are subsetted via task record types.
I can pull these record type via a simple SOQL query:

```
SELECT Name, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Task'
```

To make this useful, via API how can I:

1. Tell which record type has which values?
2. Identify the task record type for a user? 
   *I think this can be done via Page Layouts but it's not clear how*
3. Set the record type when creating a task?
   *I think this is not needed as the layout handles the assignment*

Comment: There's something in the UI-API (based on REST) that you can utilize to fetch the picklist values based on record types. Refer to the [**documentation here**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values.htm).

Comment: Thanks @JayantDas the UI API does not support the Task object unfortunately!

Comment: right you are, didn’t realize it, I had come across this during one of my tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The picklist-values-per-record-type issue is an old problem to which there's only recently a semi-decent solution. There's [a number of ways to approach this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221007/retriving-all-active-picklist-values-of-all-recordtypes/221009#221009), and if you're already using the API, the new UI API is probably the best way to go.
2. You can use a variety of routes to access record type availability. Issuing a Describe API call to, e.g., `/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe` has keys `available` (for the running user's Profile) and `defaultRecordTypeMapping`under each of the entries in the `recordTypeInfos`. The Metadata API also permits you to get [record type availability and default record type information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) at the Profile level, but it's non-trivial. The [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_profile.htm) can theoretically also yield this information, although I wasn't immediately able to get the record type visibilities that way in Workbench. (Looks like [others have had that issue too](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144894/getting-null-metadata-values-from-tooling-api)).
3. This is the easiest, but it has nothing to do with the page layout. Just set the field `RecordTypeId` on the Task you're inserting to the `Id` of the desired record type.

Note that if the Profile has exactly one custom record type associated with it, that will be [used automatically](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=permissions_record_type_access.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thanks so much David!
1. Do you know of any issues using my suggestion below with the Tooling API?
2. Didn't know about that resource but it solves it!
3. I can't see this field in the documentation, is it hidden or undocumented and "just works"

Comment: Any object that has record types enabled will have a `RecordTypeId` field. it shows up as `RecordType` in the Object Manager. I don't see any issues with your use of the Tooling API, although I haven't tried that route myself - we know that picklist information can be accessed through that door.

Comment: I forgot about going in through the Describe API, as you mentioned in your answer regarding picklist values - that's a far easier way than the Metadata API to get record type availability info. I've updated that.

Comment: I checked the UI API and it does not yet support Task. The Tooling API does provide this, except it does not return custom field data!

Comment: Yes, this doesn't return any custom field data? Does anyone else know of an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my findings so far, documented for future reference:

At first glance it seemed possible with the `describe` call on the Task object `/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Task/describe/layouts`

This yields some useful information such as `defaultRecordTypeMapping` which I think can be used to answer question 2.

There is also a field named `picklistsForRecordType` yet this returns an empty array. Probably not yet available so we are out of luck there.

Next we can check the new Tooling API: `/services/data/v43.0/tooling/sobjects/RecordType/{id}`
Here we seem to be in luck! There is a Metadata.pickListValues array that contains each picklist field on the Task object.